# ScalingFunctions scales ChartLegends and not the y-axes

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale, scaling

I type in the code:

```
histogram = DensityHistogram[EnergyTable2, ScalingFunctions -> "Log10", 
  ChartLegends -> Automatic]
```

because I want to scale the y-axis but the `ChartLegends` are scaled.

```
histogram = DensityHistogram[EnergyTable2, ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear","Log10"}, 
  ChartLegends -> Automatic]
```

doesn't work either. It gives the same as:

```
histogram = DensityHistogram[EnergyTable2, ChartLegends -> Automatic]
```

I would be so glad if someone could help me. :)

Comment: Could you share some sample data for us to play with your code? e.g. the definition of `EnergyTable2`.

Comment: For example this are the first three rows: {10.0719, 878.02}, {10.1042, 866.175}, {10.0509, 826.45}

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you wish the y-axis to be scaled logarithmically but the `ChartLegends` to remain linear.  This appears to be already the case with your code.  In the absence of data, I made some up.

```
EnergyTable2 = Abs@RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 500] + 1.;
```

Then the base case is,

```
histogram = DensityHistogram[EnergyTable2, ChartLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

and the case with the y-axis scaled logarithmically is

```
histogram = DensityHistogram[EnergyTable2, 
    ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Log10"}, ChartLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Visibly, the second histogram has its y-axis scaled logarithmically, and the color scaling of the two plots is identical.